# Debugging 24 symmetric operators

Tags: matlab, debugging

I have written the following code to calculate the disorientation between two points in a large dataset using 24 crystal symmetry operators. The code seems to work fine though the end result is not right. I have a huge dataset containing the euler angles for each points. I find the misorientation between 1st point and 2nd point and then between 2 and 3rd and so on.

I want the end result to contain the corresponding misorientaion angles for each two data points. Following is the full code for your better understanding of my requirement.

```
LA=[phi1 phi phi2];

function gi=get_gi(pvec)
%pvec is a 1x3 vector of [phi1 phi phi2]
g_11=((cosd(pvec(1)).*cosd(pvec(3)))-(sind(pvec(1)).*sind(pvec(3)).*cosd(pvec(2))));
g_12=((sind(pvec(1)).*cosd(pvec(3)))+(cosd(pvec(1)).*sind(pvec(3)).*cosd(pvec(2))));
g_13= (sind(pvec(3)).*sind(pvec(2)));
g_21 =((-cosd(pvec(1)).*sind(pvec(3)))-(sind(pvec(1)).*cos(pvec(3)).*cos(pvec(2)))); 
g_22 = ((-sin(pvec(1)).*sind(pvec(3)))+(cosd(pvec(1)).*cosd(pvec(3)).*cosd(pvec(2))));
g_23 = (cosd(pvec(3)).*sind(pvec(2)));
g_31 = (sind(pvec(1)).* sind(pvec(2)));
g_32 = -cosd(pvec(1)).* sind(pvec(2));
g_33 = cosd(pvec(2)); 

gi =[g_11 g_12 g_13;g_21 g_22 g_23;g_31 g_32 g_33];


f = [1 1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 -1];
l= [1 1 1];
for i=1:3:10    
l1= [f(i) 0 0;0 f(i+1) 0;0 0 f(i+2)];
l2= [0 f(i) 0;0 0 f(i+1);f(i+2) 0 0];
l3= [0 0 f(i);f(i+1) 0 0;0 f(i+2) 0];
l4= -[0 0 f(i);0 f(i+1) 0;f(i+2) 0 0];
l5= -[0 f(i) 0;f(i+1) 0 0;0 0 f(i+2)];
l6= -[f(i) 0 0;0 0 f(i+1);0 f(i+2) 0];
l=[l;l1;l2;l3;l4;l5;l6];
end
k=1;
t=1;


for m=1:(length(a)-1)
for i=2:3:71
    for j=2:3:71
        g_r= (get_gi(LA(m,:)*l(i:i+2,1:3))*(inv(get_gi(LA(m+1,:)))*inv(l(j:j+2,1:3))));
        tr(k)= g_r(1,1) + g_r(2,2) +g_r(3,3);
        angle(k) = real(acosd((tr(k)-1)/2));
        k=k+1;
    end
    angle(angle==0)=360;
    del_theta=min(angle)
    del(t)=del_theta;
    t=t+1;
end
```

Comment: Test it pout with a SMALL data set, only a few points, where you know the correct answers. Use the debugger, checking each line for correctness. You should never just throw a huge set at unverified code, and then wonder what is wrong. That would be just as difficult as throwing uncommented code at us, and hoping we can debug it for you.

Comment: @woodchips I am having the problem where I am doing the inversion in the 10th line from the last. I wanted the angle between each two points  and so on...please help